# HttpPost("list") что это за ("list") аннотация/модификатор?

Tags: c#, http, api, rest

У меня возможно банальный вопрос что такое:

> ("list")

для чего нужно, что еще кроме **list** бывает и где можно подробно прочитать про это, спасибо.

гуглил, много думал, пытался самостоятельно додуматься, решил обратиться именно к вам.

[image: скриншот]

Comment: [Маршрутизация с помощью атрибутов Http](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.1#attribute-routing-with-httpverb-attributes)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ так мож ответ распишете?

Comment: @tym32167 Пока нет времени к сожалению. Если есть желание, то буду не против вашего ответа)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ у меня аналогично, бегу на работу :)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ благодарю! пишите ответ как будет время - увеличим вам рейтинг.

Comment: @tym32167 успешного забега.

Comment: @Jiraff537 спасибо :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По сути, это одна из разновидностей [маршрутизации](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.1), где вы задаете URL путь до указанного метода. В вашем случае он получит примерно следующий адрес:

`Post` >> `http://site/api/relations/list`

- `api/relations` - это `[Route("api/[Controller]")]`
- `list`- это `[HttpPost("list")]`

---

Существует 3 вида маршрутизации:

1. С помощью `MapRoute` - Здесь вы просто задаете (к примеру в конфигурации) нужные пути вашего проекта, и дальше он либо по стандарту будет на весь проект распространяться.
2. С помощью атрибута `[Route("...")]` - Довольно удобный способ, где на каждый контролл/метод можно сделать свои пути (а то и несколько) без лишних действий.
3. С помощью `Http[Verb]` атрибутов - Как по мне, это самый лучший способ, где вы можете не только задать нужный маршрут, но и задать тип (post/get/put и др.) входящего запроса. Для API данный вид маршрутизации не заменим.

В общем удачи в программировании!